# how to make path for / and home in react router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

this is my routes now, which don't work:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Navbar />,
    children: [{ path: "/(home)?", element: <Home /> }],
  },
];
```

i remember working on path before for home like this:

```
<Route path="/(home)?" element={<Home />} />
```

i want to match / and /home and render Home component for both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass an array of children routes for `/` and `/home`.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Navbar />,
    children: [
      { path: '/', element: <Home /> },
      { path: 'home', element: <Home /> },
    ],
  },
]
```

Note that the `Navbar` component should render `Outlet` to render the child routes.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'

const Navbar = () => (
  <>
    <h1>Navbar</h1>
    <Outlet />
  </>
)
```

[image: Edit reverent-ellis-cn8j5]

Comment: i get error thrown:  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: @gpbaculio My bad. I was confused by the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#object-based-routes) which mentions "A route object has the same properties as a `<Route>` element." Just updated my answer with a fix.

Comment: @TJ You can click the **Embed** link at the top right and click on **Other Sharing Options** on the left sidebar in the modal that shows up.  You should then find the markdown to share the CodeSandbox link with an image in there.